# Function overloading and templates

Tags: c++, function, templates, overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <typename ReturnType, typename ArgumentType>
ReturnType Foo(ArgumentType arg){}


template <typename ArgumentType>
string Foo(ArgumentType arg) { cout<<"inside return 1"<<endl; return "Return1"; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Foo<int>(2);        
    return 0;
}
```

### The above code throws the following error.

```
In function 'int main(int, char**)': 
34:18: error: call of overloaded 'Foo(int)' is ambiguous 
34:18: note: candidates are: 
7:12: note: ReturnType Foo(ArgumentType) [with ReturnType = int; ArgumentType = int] 
20:8: note: std::string Foo(ArgumentType) [with ArgumentType = int; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]
```

Since, function overloading only accounts for the function name, parameter type list and the enclosing namespace. Why is this error being thrown?

Answer (score 2):

The call to `Foo<int>(2)` could be either:

```
ReturnType Foo(ArgumentType arg); //with ReturnType = int, ArgumentType deduced as int
```

or

```
string Foo(ArgumentType arg); //with ArgumentType = int
```

The compiler can't tell which one you wanted because they both have the same arguments:

```
int Foo(int);
string Foo(int);
```

Comment: But the function was called with one template parameter, The template function `ReturnType Foo(ArgumentType arg){}` needs two template parameter

Comment: @q126y It can deduce what the second parameter is, because it is the type of the argument.

Comment: okay, then error should not be about overloading, as it is not overloading that is causing the error.

Comment: @q126y, it is function overloading. There are two function templates with the name `Foo`.

Comment: @james but the specialized templates[which lead to error] have same function name, parameter list and enclosing name-space, so it is not case of function overloading. Please correct if I am wrong. thanks.

Comment: @q126y Two functions with the same name **is** function overloading.

Comment: @JamesRoot no, it is not https://ideone.com/lUKlim, it is redeclaration if they have same function name, parameter list and enclosing name-space

Comment: @q126y They are two distinct functions in an overload set, but when _this particular call_ is made, they turn out to be equally viable. Passing a type different than an `int` [doesn't result in an error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55478bb2ca51d5dd).

Comment: @JamesRoot Please see code in the caveat section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_template_specialization#Caveats

I understand that compiler should generate an error in my original code, but not overload error.